# What are home grown players?

Tags: football-manager-2014

What are the rules for a player to be qualified as "home grown"? I don't see anything about it on the "rules" tab in the league I'm playing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to find which of the players are home grown:

Go to **Squad**, then in a drop down list there is an item called **Home Grown Status**. This will not only show which players are "Trained in nation" (same as "Home Grown") and "Trained at club", but also a due date for the players which can attain such a status.

To be qualified as home grown, a player must be training at a club in your country for at least 3 full years between 15 and 21 years (this range is actually specified in the aforementioned home grown list). So, when a player joins your club on his 18'th birthday the only way to convert him to the home grown player is to keep him at the club until his 21'st birthday. The status is awarded as soon as the three year rule is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

As per all references I've seen so far in FM games, the game counts a player as 'home grown' if he has been in that country for a minimum of 3 years, between the ages of 16 and 21.

The same is valid for club-grown, which requires him to be on the same club (he'd get both ranks)